# How to get background image on Bootstrap jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get use an image as the background for my jumbotron and can't get the image to show. I can change the other properties of the jumbotron just fine, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with the background image.

Here's my html

```
    <header>
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-3"> Large Text </h1>
            <h1 class="display-4"> Smaller Text </h1>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Learn More »</a></p>
         </div>
        </div>
      </header>
```

...and here's my CSS

```
    .jumbotron {
        background: url("img/banner.jpg");
        color: black;
      }
```

why can't I get this to work? My filepath is definitely correct.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I had originally answered this saying that Bootstrap is probably overriding your `background` declaration. However it appears that Bootstrap doesn't use `background`, but instead uses `background-color`, so my answer was incorrect. I advise you double check to ensure your filepath is definitely correct as I believe what you have should be valid.

Comment: having just run a quick test (http://imgur.com/a/RFa73) there should be no issues with doing things the way you have done them. Why is your jumbotron in your header?

Comment: Have you checked your developer tools? Is the css rule applied to your "jumbotron" div? (right click -> inspect element might help...)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Was trying all sorts of solutions to get the image in the background of the jumbotron.  Eventually found the issue.

I was referencing the wrong css file from my html...

I know.  Basic.  But often these are the things we overlook!

Answer (score -1):

it should work see http://jsfiddle.net/C4Sjg/538/

```
.jumbotron{
    background-image: url(https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/ladislao-jose-biros-117th-birthday-5067428201496576-res.png);
    color:white;
}
```

if this doesn't work then you should inspect element your code and see what is the issue, if you could provide live link to the issue then that would easy to find issue for us too

Comment: How does this answer the question asked?

Comment: yes you are right my bad, Nate should debug the code and see whats causing the issue

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your answers everyone! I ended up taking a different route and just placed the background image I wanted in the body instead of the jumbotron. Then I just made the jumbotron background transparent so the background image came through.

Comment: Can you provide code for this solution?  It will help others that have the same issues in the future.